# iPhone error, 'Referenced-counted object is use after it is released error' ; memory leak cleanup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, memory-leaks, release-management

I am trying to clean up memory leaks and other issues in an existing iPhone app. I am a little new to Objective C, but have some good programming fundamentals and a general understanding of the memory management that is required when dev'ing iphone apps. My question is about the following method below.

```
  -(NSDate *)formatDate:(id)value{
NSLog(@"eja: DetailViewController/ formatDate()");

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
[dateFormatter release];


return [dateFormatter dateFromString:value];


}
```

It is returning an error reading "**Referenced-counted object is use after it is released**". I see that dateFormatter is being freed before it is returned/used. The issue is of course that if you put the release after the return statement you get a 'Potential leak of an object' error associated with dateFormatter var declaration.

I also tried "autorelease"

```
return [[dateFormatter dateFromString:value] autorelease];
```

But I then get the error '**Object sent - autorelease too many times**'.

Any words of advice on how to write this properly so the variables are properly managed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
[dateFormatter release];
```

with

```
[dateFormatter autorelease];
```

and it should work!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `NSDate` before you release the `NSDateFormatter`:

```
-(NSDate *)formatDate:(id)value
{
    NSLog(@"eja: DetailViewController/ formatDate()");

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:value];
    [dateFormatter release];

    return date;
}
```

This way, your allocated `NSDateFormatter` gets released as it should while the object you are returning doesn't require manual memory management.

Comment: this solution works, thank you! But if I can ask further, what happens to the variable called date? Don't I have to clear that too? Just wondering...thanks again

Comment: Also, although I would like to give checkmarks to both of you, I used phix23's solution below (but kept yours for reference). thanks again

Comment: The date variable is retained in memory for the duration of its use in this method. The downside of using @phix23's solution is that `dateFormatter` may never get released at all. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/autorelease

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `[dateFormatter release]`, you can autorelease it, and even save a line of code in the process.

```
- (NSDate *)formatDate:(NSString *)value {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:value];
}
```